# Is it possible to use a MTB with rear Boost hub with a Tacx E Blue Twist T2675 E trainer?

Tags: mountain-bike, trainer, boost

Greeting,

I want to buy a Tacx E Blue Twist T2675 E ( or any entry to medium home trainer from Tacx ) but I am not sure if it fits with my Rear Syntace X-12 - M12 12x148 Thread Pitch 1.0 Boost E-thru axle system.
I searched a lot the internet but I still couldn't find a good answer. I used this link to search for a Trainer Axle:
https://tacx.com/product/e-thru-trainer-axle/
I find that model T1711 which is for 142x12 would probably fit my requirements?
For modifying Tacx support I found this video

My frame is a MTB 4XL Promaxx 29er from Maxx.de This is the frame details: [image]

My only uncertainty is: Will T1711 be able to hold my bike? or should I make a home-made Axle like in this video?

Also, I am ~130kg naked. Will Tacx hold me and my bike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's likelier than not that the one you link to won't work with boost.
Boost/148 isn't listed in what it's compatible with. If it was made with 142 in mind it's not likely to work by coincidence, because of trainer thru-axles that are adaptable to different spacings, they do it by swapping spacers around on an axle that's long enough to accommodate whatever. I'd be suspicious of that one being long enough. And, playing games with barely sufficient thread engagement is the main way for the whole thing to go wrong.

Get a Kinetic Traxle Fine T-2100. I've yet to see one not go into whatever trainer. Remember that no matter what you do, the deal with X12 is you must have the conical interface of the frame mated with an appropriate conical washer of some sort, or you'll ruin your frame. The above Traxle has one.

Comment: I understand now perfectly. Thanks for the answer.